# How to pass one same value as argument to two methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple class as:

`connection` has db connection

```
import pandas as pd
from animal import kettle
class cat:
    def foo(connection):
        a=pd.read_sql('select * from zoo',connection)
        return1= kettle.boo1(a)
        return2= kettle.boo2(a)
        return return1,return2
```

Now I want to pass `a` to both `boo1` and `boo2` of kettle, am I passing it the correct way in above foo()?

I thought above way is correct and I tried this way , but is this correct way to pass?

### animal.py:

```
class kettle:
    def boo1(return1):
         print(return1)

    def boo2(return2):
        print(return2)
```

sorry if this doesn't make any sense,
my intention is passing `a` to both `boo1` and `boo2` of `kettle` class

Comment: Is there any indication that it wouldn't be correct? Did you think of another way how you could pass it? Does it work?

Comment: absolutely not mate, I am like if there are other possible ways to do it if at all my approach is not correct,....

Comment: it is correct. You should have tried and then check what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the correct approach to me: by assigning the return value of `pd.read_sql('select * from zoo', connection)` to `a` first and then passing `a` to `kettle.boo1` and `kettle.boo2` you ensure you only do the potentially time-consuming database IO only once.

One thing to keep in mind with this design pattern when you are passing objects such as lists/dicts/dataframes is the question of whether `kettle.boo1` changes the value that is in `a`. If it does, `kettle.boo2` will receive the modified version of `a` as an input, which can lead to unexpected behavior.

A very minimal example is the following:

```py
>>> def foo(x):
...     x[0] = 'b'
...
>>> x = ['a']  # define a list of length 1
>>> foo(x)  # call a function that modifies the first element in x
>>> print(x)  # the value in x has changed
['b']
```

Comment: `ensure you only do the potentially time-consuming database IO only once` what do you mean by this mate?

Comment: I mean that the alternative, calling `return1 = kettle.boo1(pd.read_sql('select * from zoo',connection))` and then `return2 = kettle.boo2(pd.read_sql('select * from zoo',connection))`, would produce the same result while doing the database query twice, which would cause your program to run for longer.

Answer (score 0):

There are (many) possible solutions for your problem, whatever that might be. I assume you just start out *object oriented programming in Python*, and get errors along the lines of

```
unbound method boo1() must be called with kettle instance as first argument
```

and probably want this solution:

Give your class methods an instance parameter:

```
def boo1(self, return1):
```

Instantiate the class kettle in cat.foo:

```
k = kettle()
```

Then use it like:

```
k.boo1(a)
```

Same for the boo2 method.

Also you probably want to:

```
return return1  # instead of or after print(return1)
```

as your methods return `None` at the moment.